# What's the difference between constitutional samples and tumor samples?

Tags: cancer, copy-number-variation

I think the tumor samples have two copies of the chromosomes. But for constitutional samples, do they only have one copy of the chromosomes?

Comment: Every cell has two copies of each chromosomes - except for sperm and egg cells.

Comment: ...and some cancerous cells.

Answer (score 1):

[Constitutional samples](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms?cdrid=768575) do, as you surmised, refer to germ cells (sperm or ovum). Hence they have 1 copy of DNA instead of 2.

Tumours, as they acquire more mutations, often have [aneuploidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aneuploidy), or different numbers of chromosomes, and can also have increased incidence of Xn chromosomes where X > 2. This is [polyploidy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20687471) for humans and organisms with normal 2n chromosomes.